# Transfer failed while trying to upload file of size 300MB in Azure Storage Explorer under my Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

My transfer failed while trying to upload a file of size 300MB in Azure Storage Explorer, but when I creating a new folder under my Container, I am able to upload successfully.

I would like to understand why it worked when creating a folder, but did not work when I tried to upload directly to my Container.

Comment: Could anyone please help me understand how it succeeded on creating folder for upload  files rather than directly upload to my container

Comment: Could you please provide the error or faiure message or more details about the transfer failure  if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

> Blob containers are the structures used to store blobs. An individual
> Blob container can hold anywhere from zero to an infinite number of
> individual blobs. By default, all blobs stored in a container share
> the same level of sharing, either private or public.

I tried uploading  300 MB files to blob containers(in the same folder of the container(name of the folder>>standardmode))  in azure storage explorer in both standard(both hot and cool tier)  and data lake storage which already has few files in them and uploaded successfully.
Here are images related to them:

1. *Uploaded few files first in container named  “standardmode”*

[image]

2. *Then selected  files of size 300MB to upload in the same container.*

[image]

3. *And then files got uploaded successfully.*

[image]

I then tried the same for Data Lake storage and successfully uploaded files more than 300MB in one go.

- In your case ,it may be some temporary issue

(Or)

You may check the version of the services .
Each block in a block blob can be a different size, up to the maximum size permitted for the service version in use.

[image]

Reference:
[Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-Block-Blobs--Append-Blobs--and-Page-Blobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

(or)

You may try uploading files using AzCopy command.

**References** to use AzCopy command:

- [storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)
- [Getting started with AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)